# Why can't I run a c# console application in debug mode? (MonoDevelop Issue?)

Tags: c#, mono, ide, monodevelop

Apologies if this is not the right place but I'm tearing my hair out here..

I had a solution, then I added a new '`c# console project`' through the `Add>Add New Project..` option in the solutions context menu.

I can build fine and I can right click on the console project and select '`Run Item`' and it works fine. But what I really want to work is the debugger! However, as you can see, '`Start Debugging Item`' remains greyed out:

[image]

Using the fancy new Debug/Release play button at the top doesn't help, no matter which mode I just get this:

[image]

I went looking for other configuration options and found that the defaults look just like i'd expect/want?

[image]
[image]

I also restarted the program, created some other new solutions but no difference.. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are set to build/run in Release mode.  In the first screenshot you supplied it is showing Release, set to Debug and see how you fair.

Comment: Thanks @KSdev :) but as i (poorly) explained it doesn't make any difference, i tried in debug mode and i get the same 'Attach to process' window pictured above.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are running monodevelop that shipped with Unity not the one from Xamarin

Default PATH for Unity C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\MonoDevelop

Default PATH for Xamarin C:\Program Files (x86)\MonoDevelop